# angular 2 cli returns error if using --aot

Tags: angular, aot

I have this code that works fine:

```
samplesInfo: any = [];
selectedSampleType: Object = {};
selectedSampleTypeForModal: string; // pass type as string to the child component
userFormSubmitted: boolean;

ngOnInit() {

    this.SamplesInfoService.getSamplesInfo()
        .map((res: Response) => res)
        .subscribe(
            data => {
                function hasType(value) { return value.hasOwnProperty('type'); }
                this.samplesInfo = data,
                this.selectedSampleType = this.samplesInfo.filter(hasType)[0],
                this.selectedSampleTypeForModal = this.samplesInfo.filter(hasType)[0].type,
                console.log("OLGA " + this.samplesInfo.filter(hasType)[0]);
                },
            err => { console.log(err); return Observable.of(true); }
    );

}
```

But if I try to build within CLI with the "--aot" added to the command, then I have an error: "Property 'type' does not exist on type 'Object'".

What am I doing wrong here?

Thanks,
Olga

Comment: What do you get from console.log(OLGA ...)?

Comment: Olga [Object object]

Comment: Which line is the error pointing to?

Comment: oh do console.log(OLGA, your property) Do not concat

Comment: @Z.Bagley /src/$$_gendir/app/app/component.ngfactory.ts

Answer (score 0):

My guess is this line is the culprit:

```
this.selectedSampleTypeForModal = this.samplesInfo.filter(hasType)[0].type
```

That .type at the end - it looks like TypeScript thinks that property doesn't exist.

Comment: Nope 8( If I replace it with a string like "test", I still have the same error in the build.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is most likely due to the `.subscribe()` response returning an empty data set or null before it populates with data creating a possible error. You can prevent the error from occurring on empty data sets by first running the filter to determine if there are any results (and hopefully your AOT build will no longer fail if it is making this check):

```
this.SamplesInfoService.getSamplesInfo()
    .map((res: Response) => res)
    .subscribe(
        data => {
            function hasType(value) { return value.hasOwnProperty('type'); }
            this.samplesInfo = data,
            if ( this.samplesInfo.filter(hasType) ) {
              this.selectedSampleType = this.samplesInfo.filter(hasType)[0],
              this.selectedSampleTypeForModal = this.samplesInfo.filter(hasType)[0].type,[0]);
            }
            },
        err => { console.log(err); return Observable.of(true); }
);
```